# How to get client ip address using php. But server in other country

Tags: php

I use the below condition., but it display the public ip address of server.
here i required the actual ip address of client., please help me.

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
} elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
} else {
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
```

Comment: Checkout this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/how-to-get-the-client-ip-address-in-php

Comment: Possible duplicate. You can probably find [your answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3003233/1369528)

Comment: Typically your attempt to find out the clients IP address is an indicator for a problem in your architecture. Since it is impossible to really find out such a value (technical reasons) that value obtained is of very questionable worth. Therefore relying on makes only limited sense, be it for documentation of authentication purposes. Think about if what you try to do really does make sense...

Comment: Don't you try to connect to the server from the same (development) machine?

Answer (score 1):

Use this function

```
 function get_client_ip() {
$ipaddress = '';
if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
    $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
    $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED'))
    $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');
else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'))
    $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');
else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED'))
   $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');
else if(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))
    $ipaddress = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
else
    $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
return $ipaddress;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

```
$ip = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP')?:
getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')?:
getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED')?:
getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR')?:
getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED')?:
getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
```